Building a DSSS reciever in GnuRadio
I have some questions regarding building a DSSS receiver in GnuRadio. Specifically with the correlation part. I'm having issues with correlating the m-sequence with the received signal. I have been trying to use the PN correlator block to correlate the received signal but i'm not sure if my flowgraph is configured correctly. I know the PN code of the captured signal so i'm using a GLFSR with said sequence to attempt to depread the original signal. However i'm not seeing anything in the waterfall that would be indicative of a BPSK signal and I'm not seeing any correlation peaks in the time sink.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.


you can't see whether something is BPSK or not in a waterfall plot; the spectrum doesn't care about constellation (unless it has an offset). You should be seeing peaks at the output of your PN correlator in the time sink!

Why do you simply discard the imaginary part of the complex number coming out of the PN correlator?

how do you make sure your GLFSR source starts producing the m-sequence the moment it starts in your capture?

Thanks for your reply. I'll answer your questions in order. According to most of the documentation i've looked at, when the signal is despread the spectrum should show a sharp spike which is indicative of a BPSK signal. I didn't think I needed to use the imaginary input for that block but I guess I was wrong. Your last question is what i'm trying to figure out. It some how needs to be synced because you're right, I have no idea if it starts the m-sequence at the correct time.

again, a spectrum can't tell you the constellation you're using, only that there is a correlated signal in a given bandwidth. So, what you're saying is (and that is correct!) that after correct despreading, you should see a narrowband signal in the spectrum (you just can't tell whether it's BPSK or anything else).

I understand. I know the parameters of the signal and I know that it's a DSSS BPSK signal. At the moment i'm not looking at the spectrum for said waveform but rather looking for correlation peaks in the time sink. At the moment there are none. I am not sure how DSSS correlation works in GnuRadio but that is what I am trying to learn.

So what the problem is is that you're doing two attempts at despreading, I think, I'm not sure! One is point-wise multiplication with a PN sequence coming from GLFSR source, and one is what the PN correlator block does. I think you only mean to do one, but I'm not sure.

Correct, I only meant to use one. I don't know all the details of what makes the PN correlator work but I was under the assumption that it needed a dsss signal plus a PN code. But if the PN correlator is all that is needed to correlate and despread then i'll just use that going forward. I just attempted this now but I'm still not seeing any correlation peaks. There also appears to be just be noise in the waterfall. Not sure where to proceed from here. It's been a bit difficult working on this project as there isn't much documentation online about working with DSSS in GnuRadio.

your DSSS-/m-code is relatively short, right? Some 127 entries long only, right? So why don't you just generate that sequence (as array, [+1, -1, …]), time flip it and use it as FIR filter? A FIR filter is a convolution with a coefficient vector, and convolution is the correlation with the time-inverse complex conjugate sequence.
